# Display CoreData Records

Tags: iphone, core-data, sqlite

I create an application using Coredata. I create a XML file and store all data into XML file. Then using coredata I store them into Database.

Now I want to view the all records from core data. My application create a sqlite file. But if I use select command in sqlite, there is no records displayed. But it shows "no errors".

Is there any way to view my records from core data or from Sqlite?

Comment: Display the records from Terminal or in UITableView?

Comment: I want to display records in UITableView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same issue, and need to investigated the sqlite db created by coredata. I used the free Sqlite database browser. http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/

And browsed to the path where the sqlite file is.

Comment: I known the sqlite file path. I open the sqlite in sqlite Software.  But there is no records to displayed in sqlite application. But i got all records through my program code and display all records in UITableView. But all records displayed randomly, not as entered sequence(Order). My problem is i want to view all records which are i entered order.

Comment: here is a good link to use core data and view it in a uitableview. I believe the author also uses xml initially. http://blog.sallarp.com/iphone-core-data-uitableview-drill-down/

Answer (score 2):

display / List out all the objects currently in the database

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
    entityForName:@"UserInfo" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
for (NSManagedObject *info in fetchedObjects) {
    NSLog(@"First Name: %@", [info valueForKey:@"firstname"]);
    NSManagedObject *details = [info valueForKey:@"address"];
    NSLog(@"Zip: %@", [details valueForKey:@"zip"]);
}
```