# How to get all records From CoreData Base using NSManagedObjectSubClass?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am trying to implement `CoreData` in `ios` Application,Now I want to Fetch all records from Entity `MUSTHAFA`

```
  My  NSManagedObjectedSubClass is MUSTAHFA
```

**MUSTHAFA.m**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface MUSTHAFA : NSManagedObject {
@private
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * FirstName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * Age;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * Location;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * LastName;

@end

#import "MUSTHAFA.h"


@implementation MUSTHAFA
@dynamic FirstName;
@dynamic Age;
@dynamic Location;
@dynamic LastName;

@end
```

**Adding Records to Core Data**

```
-(void)AddRecordToCoreData{

    //NSLog(@"______ ADD Core Data Implementaion");  
    MUSTHAFA *event = (MUSTHAFA *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"MUSTHAFA" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [event setLastName:@"JOHN"];
    [event setFirstName:@"JOSE "];
    [event setLocation:@"IDUKKI "];
    [event setAge:[NSNumber numberWithInt:25]];    
    NSError *error;
    if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) 
        {       
        NSLog(@"Error..%@",error);
    }
       else
       {
        NSLog(@"Data added to MUSTHAFA ");
       }      
}
```

Retrieving all Values from Core Data just like select * from dbTable;

```
-(void)FetchRecordFromCoreData:(id)data1{

     //NSLog(@"______ Fetch Core Data Implementaion");  
    MUSTHAFA *event = (MUSTHAFA *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"MUSTHAFA" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

   //USING event how can fetch all record from Data base;


}
```

USING  event (Instance of MUSTAHFA) how can fetch all record from Data base?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = //Get it from AppDelegate

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]initWithEntityName:@"MUSTHAFA"];

NSError *error = nil;

NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

if (error != nil) {

   //Deal with failure
}
else {

   //Deal with success
}

[request release];
```

Comment: what is NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]initWithEntityName:@"MUSTHAFA"]; line means

Comment: That's what it does.  If you are wanting to use CoreData, I suggest you go through a tutorial.  Here's one: http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036395/display-coredata-records/22633856#22633856

Answer (score 9):

```
AppDelegate *delegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

NSManagedObjectContext *context =[delegate managedObjectContext];

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]initWithEntityName:@"Channels"];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

ChannelDBArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (NSManagedObject *obj in results) {


    NSArray *keys = [[[obj entity] attributesByName] allKeys];
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [obj dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:keys];

}
if (error != nil) {

    //Deal with failure
}
else {

    //Deal with success
}
```